# Vim - E490: No fold found

Tags: vim, latex, vimrc, code-folding

I'm having problems folding some lines in a LaTeX. I use the `set foldmarker=/*,*/` option in my `.vimrc`, and is working fine in the main file, but when I change the buffer, in the other file, I can't fold the lines.

This is the [main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m5X8.png) file. And this is the [other file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx9qD.png).

```
set foldmarker=/*,*/
set foldnestmax=10
set nofoldenable
set foldlevel=2

autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
```

And that is what I have in my `.vimrc` to fold.